# Why can't my android ACTION_VIEW intent load a photo?

Tags: android

I am working with the Camera, trying to take, save and display images. My app allows taking a picture, and the Intent takes it successfully. I get a bitmap back. Further, it saves the file, but I cannot get the image to display.

I fixed the issue with permissions by using a FileProvider, and I know the file is saving because my code reaches inside the if(file.exists) block.  On my emulated Nexus 5X (API 25) I get "couldn't load photo", while on my physical Nexus 5X (API 27) I get a black screen with a loading circle, but no image ever loads.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 169;

private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;
protected static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";

TextView tvPath;
ImageView picture;
File destination;
String imagePath;

private Uri mSharedUri = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTvPath);
    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idIvImage);
    String name =  "test_image";
    destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");

    fixPermissions();
    fixPermissions2();

    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnTakePicture);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            Uri contentUriToShare = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    "com.weebly.stevelosk.fileprovider", destination);
            mSharedUri = contentUriToShare;

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mSharedUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test_image.jpg");
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

            if (file.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Uri contentUriToShare = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        "com.weebly.stevelosk.fileprovider", file);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(contentUriToShare, "image/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                try {
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 10;
            imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            tvPath.setText(imagePath);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            picture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else{
        tvPath.setText("Request cancelled");
        Integer reqCode = (Integer) requestCode;
        String RC = reqCode.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), RC,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void fixPermissions() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}


private void fixPermissions2() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
    }

}
```

The android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.weebly.stevelosk.cameratestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.weebly.stevelosk.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <activity
            android:name="com.weebly.stevelosk.cameratestapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the file paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />

</paths>
```

I am probably overlooking something simple, but I would appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Comment: i have updated the answer please update if it works..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it is still not working.